# Symfony2 - bind one form to multiple objects

Tags: php, symfony

I'm currently creating a form, something along the lines of:

```
$myDto = // ... etc - I am not using Doctrine

$form = $this->createForm(new DtoType(), $myDto);
$form->bind($request);
```

The values get bound to the form and end up assigned to $myDto. That's fine.

I would like to prepend a couple of extra fields to my form **for a different object**.

I could create a "composite" type which contains them both - I could call it `CompositeFormType` which contains `DtoType` (the original form) and `ActionsType` (the new fields), a bit like described here http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#embedded-forms.

If that's the best way, then once I have created this `CompositeFormType`, how would I get the values in/out of the form? What would I pass to 'createForm'? So for example:

```
$myDto =   // ... etc
$actions = // ... etc

$form = $this->createForm(new CompositeFormType(), ???);

                  //                     What here? ^
                  //
                  // I want both 'actions' and 'myDto' to be populated by
                  // the child types? How?

$form->bind($request);
```

... or should I be doing it a completely different way? Thanks in advance for your pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new class which owns both objects as properties and pass instance of this class to this composite form.